# If my search term is not found add to array

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Looping through a list of terms and searching database for each term. Is there a way to return a list of search terms that didn't find results in the database?

This is my `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT x_tbl.x_str
    FROM x_tbl
    LEFT JOIN p_tbl ON p_tbl.p_id = x_tbl.p_id
    LEFT JOIN t_tbl ON t_tbl.t_id = x_tbl.t_id
    WHERE t_tbl.t = %(uw)s
    OR    t_tbl.ta = %(uw)s
    OR    %(uw)s = ANY (t_tbl.tb)
    OR    t_tbl.tc = %(uw)s
    OR    p_tbl.pa = %(uw)s
    OR    %(uw)s = ANY (p_tbl.pb)
```

I want to return `uw` if it does not find any results in the database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to return `uw` if it does not find any results in the database.

#### For one search term

The two `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` between `x_tbl`, `p_tbl` and `t_tbl` do not eliminate any rows by themselves. Two times `NOT EXISTS` returns a list of search terms, that cannot find anything:

```sql
SELECT %(uw)s  -- old-style Python placeholder
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM p_tbl
   WHERE  pa     = %(uw)s
      OR  %(uw)s = ANY (p.pb)
   )
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM t_tbl
   WHERE  %(uw)s IN (t, ta, tc)
      OR  %(uw)s = ANY (tb)
   );
```

**If** there can be orphans in `t_tbl` and/or `p_tbl` (not linked to any row in `x_tbl`), the set may be bigger, and the query gets more expensive:

```sql
SELECT %(uw)s  -- old-style Python placeholder
WHERE  NOT EXISTS NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM x_tbl JOIN p_tbl p USING (p_id)
   WHERE  p.pa     = %(uw)s
      OR  %(uw)s = ANY (p.pb)
   )
AND (
   SELECT FROM x_tbl JOIN t_tbl t USING (t_id)
   WHERE  %(uw)s IN (t.t, t.ta, t.tc)
      OR  %(uw)s = ANY (t.tb)
   );
```

This is dealing with ***one*** search term at a time, like your original query. You mentioned a *list*. Running a single query for all of them might be (much) cheaper ...

#### One query to rule them all

Pass the list as array (Postgres array literal) - which may require an explicit cast (`::text[]`) - [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) and attach the same `WHERE` conditions as above:

```sql
SELECT uw
FROM   unnest(%(my_list_as_array)s::text[]) q(uw)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM p_tbl
   WHERE  pa = q.uw
      OR  q.uw = ANY (p.pb)
   )
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM t_tbl
   WHERE  q.uw IN (t, ta, tc)
      OR  q.uw = ANY (tb)
   );
```

Or, including the join to `tbl_x`, same as above:

```sql
SELECT uw
FROM   unnest(%(my_list_as_array)s::text[]) q(uw)
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM x_tbl JOIN p_tbl p USING (p_id)
   WHERE  p.pa     = q.uw
      OR  q.uw = ANY (p.pb)
   )
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM x_tbl JOIN t_tbl t USING (t_id)
   WHERE  q.uw IN (t.t, t.ta, t.tc)
      OR  q.uw = ANY (t.tb)
   );
```

Basics:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

You may want to keep array elements in original order, or even attach an ordinal position. See:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

---

Aside, your original query can multiply rows - **if** there can be more than one row on the right side of each join. See:

- [Two SQL LEFT JOINS produce incorrect result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464037/two-sql-left-joins-produce-incorrect-result/12464135#12464135)